# Hint Text is overlapping to my TextInputLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-textinputlayout

In my app, I have a TextInputLayout where the user enters its id, when the TextInputLayout does not have the focus looks like:

[image]

However, when the user touch the TextInputLayout (get the focus) the hint text looks like:

[image]

And I need hint text looks like as the follow image when the TextInputLayout have the focus:

[image]

Ignore the icon, its different but it does not matter in this moment, that I want to do is the hint text looks like the last image

Here is my code:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/ilUser"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:textColorHint="@color/et_login">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etUser"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/et_login_height"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_format"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/user"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:hint="@string/user_id_text_hint"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="12"
        android:minLines="15"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_drawable_app"
        android:textSize="@dimen/h5"
        android:theme="@style/EditTextTheme" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant do this by default edit text you can use some library in your app to apply this ...

library is here :

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
```

and if you want to learn i recommend to see this tutorial :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_TEugAIMHA&t=616s
see this and you can get your answer...

Answer (score 0):

When you use **TextInputLayout** is highly recommended to use **TextInputEditText** instead of **EditText**

Example:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
android:id="@+id/ilUser"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:textColorHint="@color/et_login">

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/etUser"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/et_login_height"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_format"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/user"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:hint="@string/user_id_text_hint"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:maxLength="12"
    android:minLines="15"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_drawable_app"
    android:textSize="@dimen/h5"
    android:theme="@style/EditTextTheme" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

That should solve it!